# Why is WebView faster than classic web request? (HttpURLConnection)

Tags: java, json, javafx, webview, httpurlconnection

I tested different methods to retrieve JSON from Discogs' API and it seems that a using an hidden WebBrowser (WebView) is the faster one.

The first method is the classic WebRequest:

```
public static String HttpRequest(String url)
    {
        while(true) {
            try {
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                //create connection
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                //add request header
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "TestAppBanana/0.1 +do not have any website yet, email address: ***");
                StringBuilder response;
                //read response
                try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                }
                return response.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

*Note: the while(true) is because sometimes discogs api closes connection during handshake randomly.*

The second one is using an hidden WebView:

```
private void loadWebView(String url) {
    webview = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webengine = webview.getEngine();
    webengine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        Document doc = webengine.getDocument();
                        try {
                            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

                            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                                    new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(System.err, "UTF-8")));
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    webengine.load(url);
}
```

My question is: why does the WebView loads faster?

I noticed that when the line is busy, the WebConnection could take 3/4times more than the usual. The WebView, instead, works normally.

Comment: You don't really say how you decided one was 'faster' nor is it possible to reproduce what you tried with the code you've provided.

Comment: @pvg just send a request with both methods and time them.
try this url: https://api.discogs.com/artists/434183/releases

Answer (score 0):

If you were measuring the time these methods took to execute, the WebView one is asynchronous - all the processing happens in another thread and the method itself simply returns. It can easily appear to be faster since the method execution time is not reflective of the time it took to process the network request and receive data back. Your first version, on the other hand, is synchronous.

Additionally, if you're measuring the time in this order, the first call bears the brunt of initialization - DNS lookup, the setup of java.net internals, etc. If you change the order of the calls, you'll find that the first one is typically slower. The correct way to do this measurement is by running both repeatedly.

Comment: I stopped the timer in the .changed method after checking if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) and I also printed the result first to check if the page was completely loaded.

Comment: Right, that's something you could have mentioned, along with providing one of these - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . As it stands now, the code is a huge pain to get working to even try. I did, though, and updated the answer with the explanation. It's important to describe precisely how you do your measurement because sometimes, as in this case, the problem is an error in measurement.